# Who eats my disk space?

Tags: windows, disk-space

Windows 10. Every now and then ~4Gb of my disk space vanishes into a thin air. And then mysteriously re-appears after few minutes. I need a tool to track the offending process down. Any recommendation?

Comment: Too much regulation for no reason. The response by DrMoishe Pippik actually did help in my case. I am just waiting for few more days to see that problem is really gone before I accept the answer as the solution. Strange to find bureaucracy in technical forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Virtual Memory set to different minimum and maximum sizes, the *pagefile* can grow or shrink when you have a lot of RAM in play. To prevent this, and to avoid fragmentation of the *pagefile*, [set them](https://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2016/05/10/how-to-manage-windows-10-virtual-memory.aspx) to the same value.,

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Sysinternals.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/
Process Monitor will probably be your friend.
Even if you don't find what your looking for, They are great tools to have.

Comment: great tool, I will try to use it to track down the problem when it pops up next time. For now I have adjusted the pagefile sizes as suggested by DrMoishe Pippik and it seems to have stopped.